# cannot Compile SASS into CSS but mapping looks alright

Tags: sass

I have sass installed globally in the terminal. `npm install sass -g`. I have a sass file in source folder
`$grey: #444; $red: rgb(250, 0, 0);` 
To compile the sass into css from source folder to css folder. I type:

@sass --watch source/style.scss css/style.css
The result in the terminal:
[comile sass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YfqG.png)

The style.css.map and style.css generated in css folder.
The result is style.css.map have output `{"version":3,"sourceRoot":"","sources":[],"names":[],"mappings":"","file":"style.css"}`
and The output in style.css have

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

.
So, I can see mapping looks alright.But where is my css file output. I need some pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed sass globally using `npm install sass -g` and I was compiling
sass file using `@sass --watch source/style.scss css/style.css`. That was all right with sass file declaring variables `$grey: #444; $red: rgb(250, 0, 0);`. One thing I missed was adding a colon (:) between arguments of sass --watch command, like `@sass --watch source/style.css:css/style.css`  which is usually not required if it was files only.

When I compile the file, it generated the files style.css within folder css.
The mappingURL output was shown because I was not using those variables. Which I added later as:

````
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: $grey;
 color: $red;
}
```.  
Then then css file was compiling sass file to css. That was it.
````